# Cygwin compiler path

Tags: cygwin

I have installed cygwin 64 bit, and have the path variable set up for its bin directory too. In command prompt "cygcheck -c cygwin" command also successfully displays

```
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
cygwin               1.7.23-1       OK
```

But wen I start cygwin terminal it displays this

```
C:\PROGRA~2\RATIONAL\RATION~1\NUTCROOT\mksnt\sh.exe: No such file or directory
```

Also netbeans (7.3) does not automatically detect this compiler. What can be the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The path for /usr/bin/ should already be set when you install cygwin, so by resetting it you may have actually removed the correct path.

You can see your path like this:

```
echo $PATH
```

I'd first try to remove your custom path statement, and if that doesn't work, you may have to uninstall and reinstall.